# What is this spiral-textured pipe in wall cabinet?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, pipe

I’m helping with parents' kitchen remodeling and will take down my vent hood cabinet and do away with it.  I just want vent hood straight up to ceiling for a clean modern look.  But when I look inside current cab, I see a pipe coming in and out of the wall about 10 inches in length and 1.5 inches circumference.  It looks metallic like chrome.  Can someone tell me what it is and is it possible to hire a plumber to hide it in the wall?

[image]

Comment: Pipes and tubing are described by _diameter_, by the way. :) Welcome to DIYSE.

Comment: Be aware that a range hood that far from the range won't be nearly as effective at collecting moisture and odor.

Comment: BX galvanized steel armored electric cable. Typically used where conduit is required and the situation makes conduit difficult to use.

Comment: You would hire an electrician not a plumber. Seeing that there is an outlet in the cabinet an electrician may be able to utilize that for the vent hood wiring.

Comment: If there's already power there, it makes you wonder why someone would bring more down the wall like that… unless it's actually gas.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's possible that the range hood is direct wired. It's also possible that it's a replacement since the original construction that included a plug-in range hood. Thus the outlet (which needs a cover plate!) for the original hood and the "aftermarket" BX through the cabinet for the hard-wired replacement hood that runs through the cabinet instead of through the wall.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's flexible conduit, which protects the wiring for the range hood. It was apparently added after initial construction of the home.

The first thing you do is switch off the breaker. Then disconnect the range hood and push the wire and conduit into the attic while you do your remodel, then pull it back into the range hood and reconnect. Keep the wire nuts on the wires in the meantime in case the breaker gets turned back on prematurely.

Comment: I have some of this exact conduit in my kitchen cabinets from the original build where outlets are mounted away from the wall. I think it may be a precaution against damage to the wires from shoving junk around in cabinets.